# Getting Invalid Authsub Token Error 403

Tags: api, compiler-errors, token, blogger, authsub

I am trying to authenticate my application using Blogger API but when user grant access to the application and blogger api return the token and the token i use to exchange the by sending the request on https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubSessionToken it return an error called Error 403 Invalid AuthSub Token. Kindly help me in this regard to debug the problem and solve it. Thanks in Advance

Comment: same question, seems no explain :(

Answer (score 0):

after doing some experiment, here it is some advice :

**change secure to zero**

https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&session=1&secure=**0**&next=http://www.example.com

**make sure you are requesting from http for and request in http again in future**

https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?scope=**http**://gdata.youtube.com&session=1&secure=0&next=http://www.example.com

it's worked like a charm for me...